# Can't mount shared folder from W10 host in Fedora 28 guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shared-folders, fedora-28

Up until a few weeks ago, I was running Fedora 27 in VBox on a W7 laptop, and Shared Folders worked fine. 
That machine died recently. I have a new W10 laptop, and have installed VBox 5.2.12 on my new W10 machine, and created a Fedora 28 VM in it.

I have installed the Guest Additions (I don't know a way to check this directly, but the clipboard works both ways round).

When I create a permanent Shared Folder, the mount point (/media/sf_[sharename]) gets created on the Linux guest, but it is not mounted, and I can't find a device to mount.

Comment: Are you sure it's not mounted? Check by typing the `mount` command as root on the terminal. If it's not mounted then the "device name" is literally just the name of the shared folder as configured in vbox (case sensitive). And the file system type is `vbox`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's not mounted. I've done `mount | grep [sharename]` and it comes back with nothing. And when I've tried an explicit `mount -t vboxsf [sharename] [mountpoint] it says it can't find the device [sharename].

Comment: It really does sound like guest additions are not installed... but clipboard. Are you certain the Guest Additions on the guest exactly match the version of virtualbox on the host?

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to check the Guest Additions specifically?

Comment: open the terminal in the guest and type `ls /opt`. You will see a folder name that includes the name and version of the installed version of guest additions.

Comment: Alo try typing `modinfo vboxguest` to get the version of the vboxguest editions module. Also try `lsmod | grep "vbox"` to see if both vboxsf and vboxguest modules are loaded.

Comment: Aha. `vboxguest` is there but `vboxsf` isn't. The version is claimed to be 4.16.14, rather than 5.2.12 as I expected; but /opt shows a 5-2-12 directory, so I'm guessing that the Additions version number is decoupled from the Vbox version?

Comment: In your case yes. Try installing the version that comes with your copy of virtualbox. If you installed the previous version of guest additions via your package manager uninstall them first. Then simply load up the guest os and, in vbox, go to `Devices` > `Insert Guest Additions CD Image`. The guest should detect that a CD was inserted into the optical drive. If you aren't given the option to run the routines on the disk then navigate to the disk in a root terminal and run the install with `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`. It will walk you thought the installation.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora 28 comes with VirtualBox guest additions already installed. The installed package interferes with the building of the guest additions from the ISO.

I created a new Fedora 28 VM to try it out. While dnf list shows virtualbox-guest-additions installed and a running virtualbox guest additions service running, it wasn't working at all for me. I couldn't find any information on the internet on where to look for log files or how to figure out what might be wrong.

As I said at the beginning, these installed guest additions interfere with compiling one's own version of the guest additions from the ISO (instructions at https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ for example). The build process fails.

I found that after first doing a `dnf erase virtualbox-guest-additions`, then rebooting, the guest additions compile and install correctly, and everything starts working perfectly.

Comment: This did not solve anything at all for me. The guest additions remained installed and the guest additions installer still kept crying about an "earlier version" being present and the installer threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1348433/201818), VirtualBox guest additions are already installed on Fedora. The problem is that this does **not** include the vboxsf driver kernel module that is required for mounting the shared folder.
[Here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1576832) you can find the solution: You need to add the `rpmfusion-free` repository and then install the package `akmod-VirtualBox`, which installs the missing drivers.
Reboot and enjoy!

Comment: `No match for argument: akmod-VirtualBox` after I run `dnf install akmod-VirtualBox`